# Load magento view via ajax?

Tags: magento

I have the folliwng file:

> app/design/frontend/default/site/template/checkout/cart/cartheader.phtml

I want to load this in via ajax, so that when the cart is updated, we can trigger an ajax call to get the contents of this file and update the page on the fly.

Does anybody know how I can access this file via ajax or even just from my browser so I can see the contents?

Thank you

Comment: you can call the template by your controller and action like ``controller/action/``

Comment: Ajax request is a http request you can't get it by calling path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new controller with methods from CartController.php this controller can be found in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers` . The methods to add and remove items from cart should be changed to use ajax and return json. The json returned can have the session messages - global messages block and cart header block, maybe other blocks depending on all info you want to update.
`app/design/frontend/default/site/template/checkout/cart/cartheader.phtml` is from the enterprise theme and is the template for the block `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar`. This template is set inside layout/checkout.xml

```
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="topCart" template="checkout/cart/cartheader.phtml">...</block>
```

To get it from a controller you can add it to the layout xml of that controller, or use:

```
$this->loadLayout()->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')->toHtml();
```

But inside Enterprise, this block already loads using ajax.